# Does the suid bit have any meaning for device files?

Tags: linux, permissions, files, devices

Does the [suid bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) have any special meaning for device files in Linux ?

Comment: `find /dev -perm /ugo+s` gives nothing on my machine (nor a few others I checked); does your machine have set id/sticky entries in /dev ?

Comment: You don't execute a device file so it won't have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is not. This bit is only used on executable files. It's defined in Linux kernel headers as `S_ISUID`. If you grep kernel sources for this constant, you will find that it is only used in:

- `should_remove_suid` function, which is used on FS operations that should remove SUID/SGID bit,
- `prepare_binprm` function in `fs/exec.c` which is used when prepairing executable file to set EUID on `exec`,
- `pid_revalidate` function in `fs/proc/base.c` which is used to populate procfs,
- `notify_change` function in `fs/attr.c` which is used when changing file attributes,
- `is_sxid` function in `include/linux/fs.h` which is only used by `XFS` and `GFS` specific code and `notify_change` function,
- in filesystem specific code (of course)

So it seems to me that this bit is only used (from userspace perspective) when executing files. At least on Linux.

Comment: Don't forget some of these bits serve a purpose for DIRECTories too.

Comment: @mdpc Directories are also files.

Comment: @mdpc: SUID bit on directory has a meaning at least on ext2/3 filesystem. Some other filesystems may implement some mechanisms similar to SGID bit on directories. But that's filesystem dependent so it only involves filesystem operations.

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski I don't see any effect from changing the SUID bit on a directory. What effect would you expect it to have?